# Firebase Auth and Google Sign In: Redirection slow after user is authenticated

Tags: vuejs2, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I am using the [Google Auth Provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider?authuser=0) (Google Sign in) with Firebase Auth. It works good, **but I can't figure out how to immediately redirect the signed in user to my homepage instead of the login page**. It seems that it takes a while for the redirection to "kick in" and redirect the user to the homepage. I feel that this is confusing UX for the average user and I would like to mitigate this as much as possible. *Anyone have any ideas or advice on how I can make this redirection process smoother so the user doesn't have to wait for the redirection to the homepage after authentication?*

I'll show some code and then provide a full sandbox demo below:

> `components/GoogleSignInButton.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <button type="button" @click.prevent="signInWithGoogle()">
      <slot>Sign Up Using Google</slot>
    </button>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    async signInWithGoogle() {
      try {
        const provider = new this.$fireModule.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        // await this.$fire.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
        await this.$fire.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

> `pages/login/index.vue`:

After Google sign in, the user is redirected back to the login page where his credentials are then caught and then finally he is sent to the homepage (aka, '/' path):

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <google-sign-in-button>Log in with Google</google-sign-in-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import GoogleSignInButton from "~/components/GoogleSignInButton.vue";
export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: { GoogleSignInButton },
  async mounted() {
    this.googleRedirectResult();
  },
  methods: {
    async googleRedirectResult() {
      // catch Google redirect if user signed up with Google
      try {
        const result = await this.$fire.auth.getRedirectResult();
        if (result.credential) {
          this.$router.replace("/");
        }
        return null; // if not an OAuth provider, skip
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("error in google redirect", error);
      }
    },
  },
  head() {
    return {
      name: "Login",
      title: "Login",
      meta: [
        {
          hid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content: "",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Full sandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/google-redirect-issue-forked-6y6m4?file=/components/GoogleSignInButton.vue:0-527

Comment: If it is a UX issue, you can simply make a full-page loader that appears on your login page while it's awaiting redirect. Alternatively, when using Firebase Auth, you can watch the AuthState and whenever it becomes true, just call router.push().

Comment: Thx will try some ideas out

Comment: Looks like the auth state is what is taking a couple of seconds after Google sign in. Once the auth state is true, it redirects. So, I can't use that. I'll try the full-page loader now.